# Is there a Microsoft certified SSH server?

Tags: windows, ssh

Does Microsoft actually validate SSH servers?  My manager will only allow me to use certified products not open source.  I am allow to use my putty client, so I need a ssh server that works with putty.

Comment: What if the product is both verified and open source?

Comment: What would you use a ssh server for if you had one?  You understand that even if you did install an SSH server that doesn't necessarily mean that you would get a bash shell and a *nix style environment.

Comment: Why not just use Microsoft's certified telnet server?

Comment: @Steve not to speak for the OP, but telnet is about as insecure as a remote management protocol gets. No one should be using it anywhere nowadays.

Comment: @MarkM but it is certified :-)

Comment: How is Putty allowed when it isn't Microsoft Certified? Could you get other products "allowed" in the same way? You should also know that Putty is in fact "Open Source"

Comment: What Goyuix said ;) If your manager thinks "certified" products are better for security, it's pointless if your client endpoint is not certified. Therefore, why not allow an "uncertified" server? BTW: I would guess (you might want to verify) that Windows certification quite probably does NOT check all security elements of (SSH) servers, only that they play nice with other software.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about their certification status, but [PowerShell SSH Server](http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/) has been featured on [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808410.aspx).

Surely that counts for something.

Answer (score 4):

If your manager wants closed source products (for whatever the reason) then [VShell Server](http://www.vandyke.com/products/vshell/index.html) is a choice.

Comment: But is that certified to run on Windows, that did seem to be the primary requirement.

Comment: Why not drop their sales department an email?

Comment: adamo - Thanks for the suggestion, VShell Server said they are NOT Microsoft certified Any other ideas?

Comment: You are not going to find such a product. It is important to understand what your boss wants. Boss either does not want an ssh server to be installed and for this reason he's sent you to a search in vain, or follows the "nobody ever got fired for buying IBM" doctrine, which means that his job security reflects prompt him to buy "certified" software. So what he in fact wants is some assurance that the product is legit. VShell is such a product, www.ssh.fi is another. Just do not expect a Microsoft stamp on a product not developed by them. So the trick is to find a means to make boss comfortable

Comment: NO, his boss wants to run server software of companies caring enough to actually run through the MS certiicatin process, which in itself is easy enough to pass for any vendor who cares. EVERY sensible approach. Stupid vendors not realizing this.

Comment: Is there a link to this process? Maybe we can push windows ssh vendors to go through it then

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately your only choice is [FortressSSH](http://pragmasys.com/FortressSSHServer.asp) . Searching through every SSH server I could find it was the only marked as Windows Certified